# Not able to load chunks in angular 2 webpack 2

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

Hi have one chunk mapped to /cart/ route and when I try to load it chrome throws

`Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/MyProject/dist/js0.chunk.js` error.

Apart from this shouldn't the path be `file:///D:/MyProject/dist/js/0.chunk.js` ?

Here is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
     cache: true,
     entry: './src/ts/main.ts',
     output: {
         path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/js/'),
         publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/js/'),
         filename: '[name].bundle.js',
         chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
     },
     resolve: {
         extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
     },
     module: {
         loaders: [{
                 test: /\.ts$/,
                 loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular-router-loader']
             },
             {
                 test: /\.scss$/,
                 loader: "css-loader!sass-loader"
             }
         ]
     },
     devServer: {
         contentBase: './dist'
     }
 };
```

Comment: I think the browser simply is not allowed to load files from the local filesystem. You should serve your project on a local development server.

Comment: Yeah I am using one, I tried using both gulp-webserver and webpack-dev-server